# TSQL recursive query help parent-child

Tags: t-sql, recursion, parent-child, recursive-query

I'm trying to build a t-sql query that will return parent and its child accounts in the same table based on a roll-up input. Can someone please assist?

```
***TABLE:USERS*** 
 UserId  ParentId  
 66      -1
 67      -1
 68      -1
 69      54
 70      55
 71      56
 72      57
```

This is what I have so far, but it only returns one account, which is the last one and I need to include the ParentId in the recursion so it will pull the list of the parent and the child accounts one after the other.

```
    DECLARE @RollUp AS bit 
    DECLARE @ParentID As INT 
    SELECT @RollUp = 0 
         If @Rollup = 1 SELECT @ParentID = CASE WHEN ParentID = -1 
         THEN Users.USER_ID 
         Else ParentID END 
    FROM Users WHERE user_Id  IN (70,71) ELSE 
    SELECT @ParentID = Users.USER_ID 
    FROM Users WHERE USER_Id  IN (70,71) ;
    WITH TRAVERSE_TREE_CTE AS 
    (  
    Select User_ID,ParentID 
    FROM Users 
    WHERE User_ID = @ParentID 
    UNION ALL Select Users.User_ID, Users.ParentID 
    FROM TRAVERSE_TREE_CTE INNER 
    JOIN Users 
    ON TRAVERSE_TREE_CTE.User_ID = Users.ParentID
    )
    Select * from Users 
    where User_id IN (SELECT distinct User_ID FROM TRAVERSE_TREE_CTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing an absolute in the recursion is the issue I think.

```
Where User_ID = @ParentID
```

You do the predicate after the recursion part not during usually.  You may at times but an absolute in the recursive expression generally will give unpredictable results as you are trying to put an explicit and join to it's parent on only one instance.  But you often need to also tell the expression which level of recursion you are looking for and the predicates after that level has been determined.

Here is an example that self populates that may help.  It will look for the max recursive level and determine ONLY that level.

```
Declare @table table ( PersonId int identity, PersonName varchar(512), Account int, ParentId int, Orders int);

insert into @Table values ('Brett', 1, NULL, 1000),('John', 1, 1, 100),('James', 1, 1, 200),('Beth', 1, 2, 300),('John2', 2, 4, 400);

select 
    PersonID
,   PersonName
,   Account
,   ParentID
from @Table

; with recursion as 
    (
    select 
        t1.PersonID
    ,   t1.PersonName
    ,   t1.Account
    --, t1.ParentID
    ,   cast(isnull(t2.PersonName, '')
            + Case when t2.PersonName is not null then '\' + t1.PersonName else t1.PersonName end
            as varchar(255)) as fullheirarchy
    ,   1 as pos
    ,   cast(t1.orders + 
            isnull(t2.orders,0) -- if the parent has no orders than zero
            as int) as Orders
    from @Table t1
        left join @Table t2 on t1.ParentId = t2.PersonId
    union all
    select 
        t.PersonID
    ,   t.PersonName
    ,   t.Account
    --, t.ParentID
    ,   cast(r.fullheirarchy + '\' + t.PersonName as varchar(255))
    ,   pos + 1  -- increases
    ,   r.orders + t.orders
    from @Table t
        join recursion r on t.ParentId = r.PersonId
    )
, b as 
    (
    select *, max(pos) over(partition by PersonID) as maxrec  -- I find the maximum occurrence of position by person
    from recursion
    )
select *
from b
where pos = maxrec  -- finds the furthest down tree
-- and Account = 2  -- I could find just someone from a different department
```

**UPDATED**

If you just want to see child elements related to a variable ID you can join a table back onto itself without using recursion.

```
Declare @table table ( PersonId int identity, PersonName varchar(512), Account int, ParentId int, Orders int);

insert into @Table values ('Brett', 1, NULL, 1000),('John', 1, 1, 100),('James', 1, 1, 200),('Beth', 1, 2, 300),('John2', 2, 4, 400);

declare @Id int = 1  -- set to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

select 
    a.PersonName
,   isnull(b.PersonName,'No Child') as [ChildName(s)]
from @table a 
    left join @table b on a.Personid = b.ParentId
where a.PersonId = @Id
```

Comment: I only need results from selected user_Ids and their respective child associations for the ids within the WHERE clause, not all results. That doesn't help.

Comment: You don't need to use recursion unless you are having an ever changing structure of heirarchy.  If you just want to find child elements just do a join back to itself.  from thing a join thing b on a.id = b.parentid.  b.(columnname) now relates to child elements which may be one or many.  See updated.

Comment: I want to find parent and child elements for several user_ids which will require a WHERE user_id IN ( ) clause. How can I iterate through those user_ids, find the child elements and select them?

Comment: As long as the ParentID and ID match up you can have many sets with the same parent or vice versa.  If the level is only one deep you can do the updated example.  Recursion is done typically when you don't know how far down something goes or if some levels are longer or shorter than others.  If you just have a table where you have say 20 members having parent A and 15 having parent B, the updated should work.